# SymmetricDS SQL Server error while reading the database metadata

Tags: sql-server, symmetricds

SQL Server version is 2016 (v13.0.4259.0), platform NT64x.

I am trying to test connection to SQL Server by doing command from SymmetricDS bin like this:

```
dbsql --engine store-001
```

store-001 properties contains

```
engine.name=store-001
db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.16.123:1433/crawlers_sm;useCursors=true;bufferMaxMemory=10240;lobBuffer=5242880
db.user=user
db.password=password
registration.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000
group.id=store
external.id=001
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
```

However it returns Exception:

```
An exception occurred.  Please see the following for details:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid(JtdsConnection.java:2833)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:590)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:334)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:653)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:109)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:649)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:531)
        at org.jumpmind.db.util.ResettableBasicDataSource.createDataSource(ResettableBasicDataSource.java:55)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)
        at org.jumpmind.db.platform.JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.determineDatabaseNameVersionSubprotocol(JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.java:271)
 [wrapped] org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Error while reading the database metadata: null
        at org.jumpmind.db.platform.JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.determineDatabaseNameVersionSubprotocol(JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.java:287)
        at org.jumpmind.db.platform.JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.create(JdbcDatabasePlatformFactory.java:238)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.ClientSymmetricEngine.createDatabasePlatform(ClientSymmetricEngine.java:367)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.ClientSymmetricEngine.createDatabasePlatform(ClientSymmetricEngine.java:326)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractCommandLauncher.getDatabasePlatform(AbstractCommandLauncher.java:287)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.DbSqlCommand.executeWithOptions(DbSqlCommand.java:73)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.AbstractCommandLauncher.execute(AbstractCommandLauncher.java:153)
        at org.jumpmind.symmetric.DbSqlCommand.main(DbSqlCommand.java:42)
```

I tried to connect on Oracle database same way and it worked.
Then I try to google exception but did not find anything helpful.
Checked symmetricds compatibility and seems it is compatible.

Comment: jtds is a really old driver, and it doesn't implement all Connection-methods because... reasons. You should use newer microsoft jdbc driver instead

Comment: jTDS hasn't seen a release in 10 years, it doesn't support any of the language features or platform semantics on newer versions of Azure/SQL Server, and even back in 2013 it wasn't completely functional. If you take a look at its source code you'll find 260 instances of `throw new AbstractMethodError` for work that never got finished, especially around code related to `nchar`, `ntext` and `nvarchar` data types. Just use [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) and call it a day.

Comment: I already did download the JDBC driver, I unpacked and I was like.. not what? I'm not sure how to implement it in SymmetricDS properties. If anyone knows that would help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments I figure out.
In symmetricds properties file had to change this lines.

```
db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.16.123:1433;databaseName=crawlers_sm;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use the JTDS driver, you will need to specify `db.validation.query` in your engine file. For Microsoft SQL Server, it is `Select 1` like as follows:

```
db.validation.query=Select 1
```